# Unique Opens no working

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, data-views

```
select
d.envios,
x.aberturas,
d.data_envio,
d.nome_email,
d.jobid,
pct_abertura = cast((x.aberturas*100/d.envios) as decimal(5,2))


from DE_BK_CV_DASHBOARD_JORNADA_FOPA d 

left join (
        select
        count(o.subscriberkey) as aberturas,
        cast(o.EventDate as date) as Data_envio,
        j.EmailName as Nome_Email,
        j.jobid
        
        from _Job j
        join _Open o on o.jobid = j.jobid
        Join _JourneyActivity ja on o.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID and lower(ja.activitytype) like '%email%'
        join _Journey jn on ja.VersionID = jn.VersionID and jn.JourneyName like 'JB_BK_CV_Fopa_PrimeiroAcesso'
        where o.isunique = 'true'
        
        group by cast(o.EventDate as date), j.EmailName,j.jobid
    ) x on x.Data_envio = d.data_envio and d.nome_email = x.nome_email
```

My automation is still getting the not unique opens, did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Underscores are wildcards in `LIKE` conditionals in T-SQL.  You'll need to escape those with square brackets.
- `lower()` isn't needed as the underlying SQL Server database is case-insensitive
- `isUnique` is a Boolean data type, which is a bit.  It can be represented with a `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`.

```sql
select
  d.envios
, x.aberturas
, d.data_envio
, d.nome_email
, d.jobid
, pct_abertura = cast((x.aberturas*100/d.envios) as decimal(5,2))
from DE_BK_CV_DASHBOARD_JORNADA_FOPA d 
left join (

  select
    count(o.subscriberkey) as aberturas
  , cast(o.EventDate as date) as Data_envio
  , j.EmailName as Nome_Email
  , j.jobid
  from _Job j
  inner join _Open o on o.jobid = j.jobid
  inner Join _JourneyActivity ja on o.TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID = ja.JourneyActivityObjectID  
  inner join _Journey jn on ja.VersionID = jn.VersionID 
  where o.isunique = 1
  and ja.activitytype like '%email%'
  and jn.JourneyName like '%JB[_]BK[_]CV[_]Fopa[_]PrimeiroAcesso%'
  group by cast(o.EventDate as date), j.EmailName, j.jobid

) x on x.Data_envio = d.data_envio and d.nome_email = x.nome_email
```

If your looking to return values from a specific JourneyName, you many not need the `like` at all.